# How to pass db info to html template to query db in Flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

My homepage queries the database to list all recipes. I wrapped it in an `<a>` tag and will build a template to show detailed info, but how do I get info about which one was clicked? I just need to grab the ID or recipe name so I could query the db and get relevant info to populate.

Python:

```
@views.route('/')
def home():
    rows = recipeMaster.query.all()
    return render_template("index.html", rows=rows)
```

HTML:

```
{% for row in rows %}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <a id = 'recipeBase' href = {{ url_for("views.recipeBase") }}>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.recipe_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb that might just do the trick. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Ended up working. Thank you!